# Creating a custom DataFormatString

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, boundfield

I have truncated data, for example the data is stored as "r" in the Database but I want to show it in a GridView as "Returning Student", is it possible to create a custom DataFormatString to handle this?

Currently the only solution I've found to custom format truncated data would be a TemplateField with a custom method in the ItemTemplate. This can get messy.

Is there a way to write a custom DataFormatString, say {0:Student} that will custom format the data based on a switch statement or other return method?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".